# sum all the value of a column in a table in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have column with the name `number` and table name `data`.

The column number has numbers in range 1-9.(just some data)

I need to sum all these values in the column. How do i do that?

Any easy simple command. I tried `sum(number)` but not coming

Comment: what you have tried with `sum(number)`??

Comment: $web = mysql_query("select SUM(number)  FROM data");
$web_sum=mysql_fetch_assoc($web);
echo $web_sum;

Comment: As stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: thats not a sql problem i think.. you shud fetch assoc with column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this.

```
$web = mysql_query("select SUM(number) as sumNumber FROM data"); 
$web_sum=mysql_fetch_assoc($web); 
echo $web_sum['sumNumber'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could check this and play some ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/191ca/1

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name
```

[MYSQL SUM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)